Why do my variable keep changing everytime i type into the Answer Component
Hello i am new in React and i am trying to create a simple math "Level" component, in the interest of reusability i want to pass the amount of varialbes in the problem(currently 2), so i am generating them using the "varialbes" variable
  const variables=GenerateVaribles(numOfVariables,min,max)
The function:
function GenerateVaribles(numOfVariables,min,max){
  const variables = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++) {
    const value =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    variables.push(value);
  }
  return variables;
}

Problem:
Everytime i write anything into the input field all of the variables with in the array change
The input component:
function Answer({inputValue,inputValueText,solution,remake,pointsChange,setSolved}){



    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        if(solution== Number(inputValueText)){
          console.log("Correct!!!!!!!!")
          setSolved(1)
          pointsChange("Add")
          remake()
          inputValue("")
        }else{
          setSolved(0)
          pointsChange("Remove")
          inputValue("")
        }
      }
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
      inputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return(
      <input value={inputValueText} className="solution" onKeyDown={handleKeyPress} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
    )
  }

Here is the relevant code:
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Timer from './Timer.jsx'


function GenerateVaribles(numOfVariables,min,max){
  const variables = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfVariables; i++) {
    const value =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    variables.push(value);
  }
  return variables;
}
function Level({solutionTime,digits,numOfVariables}) {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);
  const [min,max]=getMax(digits)
  const variables=GenerateVaribles(numOfVariables,min,max)
  const [vari1, setVari1] = useState(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
  const [vari2, setVari2] = useState(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
  const [theSolution, setTheSolution] = useState(GetSolution(variables));
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [pointsClass, setPointsClass]=useState("");
  // 0 means it is not solved and 1 is solved
  const [isSolved,setIsSolved]=useState(0)

  const generateNewProblem = () => {
    const newVari1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    const newVari2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    setVari1(newVari1);
    setVari2(newVari2);
    setTheSolution(newVari1 + newVari2);
  };
  const handlePointChange=(action,amount=1)=>{
    if(action=="Add"){
      setPoints(points + amount)
    }
    if(action=="Remove"){
      setPoints(points - amount)
    }
  }

  const clearValue =()=>{
    setInputValue("")
  }
  useEffect(() => {
  },[isSolved]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(points<0){
      setPointsClass("negativePoints")
    }else{
      setPointsClass("positivePoints")
    }
  },[points]);


  return (
    <>

      <div className="MainBody">
        <Timer time={solutionTime} resetter={isSolved} setSolved={setIsSolved} newProblem={generateNewProblem} pointsChanger={handlePointChange}/>
          <Problem 
          variablesArray={variables}
          var1={vari1} 
          var2={vari2} 
          setInputValue={setInputValue} 
          value={inputValue}
          solution={theSolution}
          remake={generateNewProblem}
          points={points}
          pointsChange={handlePointChange}
          setSolved={setIsSolved}
          pointsClass={pointsClass}
          />
          

          <Button 
          text="Check Solution"
          solution={theSolution} 
          inputValueText={inputValue}
          remake={generateNewProblem}
          clear={clearValue}
          points={points}
          setPoints={setPoints}
          setIsSolved={setIsSolved}
          />

      </div>
    </>
  )
}

// ----------------------------Child 1-----------------------------------  
function Problem({variablesArray,var1,var2,setInputValue,value,solution,remake,points,pointsChange,setSolved,pointsClass}){
  let html=""
  for(let i=0;i<variablesArray.length;i++){
    html=html+variablesArray[i]
    if(!(i+1>=variablesArray.length)){
    html=html+ "+"
    }

  }


  return(
    <div className="Problem">
      <div className='ProblemHeader'>
        <span className={"pointsCounter"}>Points:<span className={pointsClass}>{points}</span></span>
        <Skipper remake={remake}/>
      </div>
      <p>{html}={value}</p>
      <Answer inputValue={setInputValue} inputValueText={value} solution={solution} remake={remake}          
          pointsChange={pointsChange}
          setSolved={setSolved}
          />
    </div>
  )
}


  function Answer({inputValue,inputValueText,solution,remake,pointsChange,setSolved}){



    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        if(solution== Number(inputValueText)){
          console.log("Correct!!!!!!!!")
          setSolved(1)
          pointsChange("Add")
          remake()
          inputValue("")
        }else{
          setSolved(0)
          pointsChange("Remove")
          inputValue("")
        }
      }
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
      inputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return(
      <input value={inputValueText} className="solution" onKeyDown={handleKeyPress} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
    )
  }


I am expecting the variables to remain the same untill the generateNewProblem() function is called
(I am aware i haven't implemented the array into it, it still works with hard coded values)

If you want the data to be stored between each render of the Level component, you will need to store it in state (or another managed React store)

Your variables variable is recreated on each render of the component, which happens every time any state changes within it. You just need to convert it to useState, like const [variables] = useState(() => GenerateVaribles(numOfVariables,min,max))

@SergeySosunov Thank you this fixed it, i tried at first to use it but i was trying to use it like a normal array ' const [variables,setVariable]  ' and then running the function inside setVariable.
